# spritekit toggling image as it moves to touchpoint

Tags: sprite-kit

using spritekit, i have a sprite that is moving from a point to the touched point on the screen.  It is using the moveTo SKAction

```
SKAction moveTo:self.newPoint duration:realMoveDuration];
```

(the sprites are actually made up of .ico files, so using a texture will not really work.)

Question is, how do you toggle the sprites during the moveTo operation?

take for example a man walking in the garden, and with each step, i would like to display a different sprite (left foot forward, then right foot forward, then left foot forward)   until the touched position has been reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/45152/sprite-kit-tutorial-animations-and-texture-atlases

It explains how to animate a texture-atlas to create a walk cycle. I don't know why you are using .ico files, but PNG files are usually easier to work with...

Comment: I went ahead and converted them into .PNG files, and setup textures.  thank you